align customPaint on top of Image in a Stack
I have an image and an set of polygons (defined by array of points [x1,y1,x2,y2...]). I want to create a Stack in which the image and the customPaint overlay with the polygons would be aligned pixel-to-pixel. The image should be able to scale (zoom) and and move (pan).
I tried all of the containers, boxes and positioning widgets I could find but none of them seem to work. When the screen_width == image_width, the pink customPaint overlay aligns fine. But when the user resizes the app, the alignment is off.
How can I make the image and the customPaint overlay scale and move together, so they are always aligned?
Example (can be pasted into dartpad):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: const WallPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WallPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/';

  const WallPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("User Browse Boulder"),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const ClimbingWall(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClimbingWall extends StatelessWidget {
  const ClimbingWall({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    // Target size based on screen dimensions
    final targetHeight = screenHeight * 0.6;
    final targetWidth = screenWidth;

    // Original image dimensions (replace with actual dimensions)
    const originalImageWidth = 6400.0; // Example values
    const originalImageHeight = 4247.0;

    // Calculate scaling factors
    final widthScale = targetWidth / originalImageWidth;
    final heightScale = targetHeight / originalImageHeight;

    return Center(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        panEnabled: true,
        scaleEnabled: true,
        minScale: 1.0,
        maxScale: 10.0,
        boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: targetWidth,
          height: targetHeight,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Image.network(
                'https://static.api.boulderama.cz/static/walls/32da338c-f6b2-4abf-88a9-647923166afe.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                width: targetWidth,
                height: targetHeight,
              ),
              CustomPaint(
                size: Size(targetWidth, targetHeight),
                painter: HoldPainter(
                  holds: holds,
                  widthScale: widthScale,
                  heightScale: heightScale,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HoldPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<List<double>> holds;
  final double widthScale;
  final double heightScale;

  HoldPainter({
    required this.holds,
    required this.widthScale,
    required this.heightScale,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.pink
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    for (final hold in holds) {
      final points = <Offset>[];
      final data = hold;
      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
        points.add(Offset(
          data[i] * widthScale,
          data[i + 1] * heightScale,
        ));
      }

      final path = Path()..addPolygon(points, true);
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

// polygon data
const List<List<double>> holds = [
  [
    5090.79,
    948.06,
    5079.42,
    959.7,
    5074.93,
    978.08,
    5076.2,
    994.92,
    5083.63,
    1006.56,
    5096.82,
    1016.8,
    5114.64,
    1020.03,
    5141.02,
    1020.17,
    5172.44,
    1020.17,
    5202.33,
    1014.56,
    5226.32,
    1002.07,
    5241.75,
    989.3,
    5248.21,
    970.92,
    5246.66,
    951.84,
    5239.09,
    935.71,
    5225.34,
    925.19,
    5207.1,
    925.19,
    5187.74,
    932.34,
    5163.75,
    939.78,
    5145.09,
    940.9,
    5113.94,
    941.88
  ],
  [
    4008.19,
    1797.46,
    4062.6,
    1751.81,
    4049.24,
    1654.47,
    4076.09,
    1659.21,
    4093.6,
    1660.36,
    4113.42,
    1660.5,
    4141.12,
    1660.93,
    4162.23,
    1660.93,
    4189.65,
    1656.63,
    4208.74,
    1651.89,
    4225.97,
    1672.99,
    4248.36,
    1717.21,
    4244.05,
    1802.34,
    4226.4,
    1830.05,
    4191.22,
    1833.78,
    4157.92,
    1834.93,
    4121.17,
    1831.19,
    4085.71,
    1826.03,
    4058.15,
    1819.14,
    4027.14,
    1807.36
  ],
  [
    4386.92,
    3249.82,
    4378.8,
    3246.97,
    4374.75,
    3265.64,
    4373.73,
    3285.93,
    4364.8,
    3296.89,
    4360.34,
    3315.96,
    4362.17,
    3330.77,
    4367.85,
    3345.79,
    4377.38,
    3354.51,
    4388.34,
    3361.21,
    4399.5,
    3353.3,
    4396.25,
    3324.69,
    4398.28,
    3307.44,
    4401.53,
    3291.82,
    4396.66,
    3273.76
  ],
  [
    5154.11,
    3331.54,
    5160.97,
    3343.94,
    5179.18,
    3346.58,
    5206.62,
    3342.88,
    5224.56,
    3332.86,
    5235.91,
    3320.98,
    5243.83,
    3306.47,
    5247.78,
    3289.58,
    5243.56,
    3279.02,
    5233.54,
    3275.07,
    5207.41,
    3278.5,
    5186.04,
    3289.58,
    5166.51,
    3306.47,
    5159.91,
    3318.61
  ],
  [
    5255.93,
    2737.93,
    5232.08,
    2742.85,
    5217.05,
    2759.96,
    5206.68,
    2769.04,
    5189.05,
    2778.37,
    5177.38,
    2784.07,
    5177.12,
    2794.96,
    5182.05,
    2803.52,
    5196.31,
    2809.48,
    5210.57,
    2808.7,
    5222.23,
    2802.22,
    5235.71,
    2798.07,
    5256.45,
    2797.55,
    5271.75,
    2800.41,
    5280.3,
    2807.4,
    5277.71,
    2816.22,
    5265.52,
    2821.92,
    5251.53,
    2827.88,
    5237.27,
    2831.0,
    5229.75,
    2838.25,
    5227.68,
    2846.03,
    5227.93,
    2856.66,
    5231.3,
    2866.51,
    5239.86,
    2873.51,
    5254.12,
    2878.7,
    5261.9,
    2877.66,
    5283.67,
    2873.51,
    5310.37,
    2862.88,
    5333.45,
    2847.85,
    5343.3,
    2829.44,
    5348.22,
    2810.77,
    5341.74,
    2785.37,
    5323.08,
    2762.04,
    5293.52,
    2743.89
  ],
  [
    3750.46,
    3951.13,
    3735.75,
    3946.3,
    3717.36,
    3943.08,
    3705.63,
    3943.31,
    3685.4,
    3943.77,
    3670.92,
    3954.58,
    3660.12,
    3967.45,
    3651.15,
    3978.25,
    3644.94,
    3989.52,
    3637.82,
    4004.46,
    3636.67,
    4018.94,
    3640.58,
    4034.12,
    3646.09,
    4045.61,
    3656.21,
    4055.04,
    3667.01,
    4062.62,
    3677.36,
    4064.0,
    3685.86,
    4059.64,
    3698.97,
    4053.89,
    3708.85,
    4049.75,
    3721.5,
    4052.28,
    3732.53,
    4057.11,
    3738.97,
    4060.55,
    3751.38,
    4064.92,
    3759.2,
    4060.1,
    3764.26,
    4052.74,
    3774.14,
    4038.95,
    3785.87,
    4026.07,
    3791.15,
    4017.8,
    3792.07,
    4004.69,
    3792.07,
    3992.05,
    3789.08,
    3981.24,
    3781.73,
    3972.28,
    3769.77,
    3962.39,
    3757.82,
    3956.41
  ],
  [
    5047.61,
    207.16,
    5043.21,
    234.08,
    5045.53,
    260.53,
    5055.5,
    293.94,
    5072.67,
    320.39,
    5094.71,
    336.86,
    5122.09,
    348.7,
    5153.65,
    354.96,
    5189.15,
    356.82,
    5217.22,
    349.62,
    5242.97,
    341.5,
    5268.26,
    323.17,
    5293.55,
    298.81,
    5310.96,
    269.11,
    5318.15,
    238.72,
    5317.92,
    202.75,
    5309.1,
    171.43,
    5292.63,
    139.88,
    5271.05,
    117.14,
    5238.8,
    99.51,
    5206.32,
    91.62,
    5166.64,
    94.4,
    5133.0,
    106.47,
    5107.47,
    122.71,
    5086.13,
    140.34,
    5070.12,
    160.06,
    5057.59,
    181.87
  ],
  [
    5757.17,
    654.06,
    5747.6,
    663.33,
    5746.28,
    692.62,
    5753.2,
    699.69,
    5811.19,
    704.55,
    5823.84,
    697.19,
    5835.91,
    669.66,
    5825.61,
    658.62
  ],
  [
    4789.47,
    1198.64,
    4783.72,
    1208.81,
    4790.36,
    1224.73,
    4809.11,
    1242.25,
    4829.99,
    1250.92,
    4857.06,
    1255.79,
    4882.18,
    1250.65,
    4897.48,
    1242.34,
    4903.15,
    1234.11,
    4903.59,
    1224.82,
    4885.9,
    1210.4,
    4855.82,
    1199.08,
    4817.51,
    1194.75
  ],
  [
    4114.44,
    3579.98,
    4104.07,
    3583.02,
    4095.91,
    3591.18,
    4084.98,
    3602.11,
    4074.05,
    3609.58,
    4064.37,
    3621.62,
    4059.25,
    3636.14,
    4056.48,
    3650.53,
    4057.59,
    3667.68,
    4058.97,
    3682.48,
    4064.51,
    3697.97,
    4070.46,
    3708.35,
    4079.72,
    3717.06,
    4088.3,
    3719.69,
    4104.62,
    3719.0,
    4117.63,
    3712.64,
    4131.46,
    3709.87,
    4143.35,
    3704.06,
    4157.74,
    3696.18,
    4172.54,
    3685.66,
    4190.52,
    3676.26,
    4201.04,
    3662.42,
    4205.74,
    3648.87,
    4206.16,
    3633.24,
    4202.97,
    3615.67,
    4193.84,
    3603.5,
    4176.14,
    3591.18,
    4160.09,
    3584.13,
    4142.52,
    3581.64,
    4128.42,
    3580.67
  ],
  [
    4663.93,
    1929.72,
    4783.03,
    1848.41,
    4800.78,
    1846.69,
    4813.67,
    1839.53,
    4831.42,
    1827.51,
    4848.02,
    1805.17,
    4852.32,
    1790.86,
    4846.59,
    1776.83,
    4799.92,
    1695.23,
    4829.13,
    1694.37,
    4865.77,
    1698.95,
    4911.01,
    1709.55,
    4941.07,
    1718.71,
    4972.85,
    1727.01,
    5000.91,
    1739.32,
    5019.24,
    1747.91,
    5034.98,
    1755.93,
    5008.07,
    1788.28,
    5000.05,
    1801.17,
    4995.19,
    1831.23,
    4998.62,
    1840.96,
    5014.08,
    1852.7,
    5025.82,
    1864.73,
    5042.14,
    1892.21,
    5051.24,
    1903.13,
    5072.7,
    1909.31,
    5088.64,
    1909.31,
    5194.68,
    2018.6,
    5189.8,
    2027.71,
    5186.88,
    2044.62,
    5189.15,
    2058.94,
    5210.95,
    2093.42,
    5217.13,
    2110.66,
    5246.73,
    2162.7,
    5236.97,
    2172.78,
    5222.98,
    2183.52,
    5201.19,
    2187.75,
    5183.95,
    2187.75,
    5170.61,
    2180.59,
    5148.82,
    2164.98,
    5123.77,
    2146.11,
    5074.01,
    2108.7,
    5032.04,
    2080.08,
    4977.02,
    2049.51,
    4936.63,
    2026.62,
    4912.37,
    2017.04,
    4900.99,
    1992.48,
    4891.1,
    1982.0,
    4877.63,
    1973.01,
    4862.35,
    1972.71,
    4843.18,
    1978.7,
    4824.02,
    1987.39,
    4797.66,
    1980.8,
    4760.22,
    1970.62,
    4733.57,
    1966.42,
    4706.01,
    1955.94,
    4683.25,
    1946.66
  ],
];




Forgot to add, if there is any better way to do this (library, different approach etc.), I am more than happy to accept any working solution.

@pskink How can I apply this to polygons? I tried to implement it using the suggested Positioned.fromRect but with no luck. Could you be more specific or provide a demo please?

i made your "holds" interactive: you can click them and some default action will be performed (in my case it will zoom the "hold" to show it at maximum size) - it is done by using Positioned.fromRect that uses Container with ShapeDecoration and custom HoldShape shape,  check this code:
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:path_drawing/path_drawing.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
      body: ClimbingWall(
        image: const NetworkImage('http://localhost/flutter/32da338c-f6b2-4abf-88a9-647923166afe.webp'),
        imageSize: const Size(6400, 4247),
        holds: [
          (holdsPathData[0], Colors.red),
          (holdsPathData[1], Colors.pink),
          (holdsPathData[2], Colors.yellow),
          (holdsPathData[3], Colors.red),
          (holdsPathData[4], Colors.pink),
          (holdsPathData[5], Colors.yellow),
          (holdsPathData[6], Colors.red),
          (holdsPathData[7], Colors.pink),
          (holdsPathData[8], Colors.yellow),
          (holdsPathData[9], Colors.red),
          (holdsPathData[10], Colors.pink),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

const holdsPathData = [
  'M5077.8 981.7c2.3 50.2 59.9 36.4 94.7 35.9 26.5-2.7 80-13.7 74.3-68-10.7-24.6-34.4-22.2-46.9-19.1s-14.9 10.2-46 15.6c-31 5.3-67.4-11.8-76.1 35.6z',
  'm4011 1797.7 51.8-48.1-13-97c30.2 7.7 24.2 9 55 9 27 0 84.1-1.3 118.8-8 13.5 21.3 18.9 38.8 30.7 62l-9.5 85-18 30c-23 2.7-37.9 1.2-69 2-31.1.7-106.9-6.9-146.8-35z',
  'M4377.1 3248.4c-6.6 4-3.4 26-5.5 35.8s-10.3 14.6-10.8 29.4c-.9 26.1 6.9 57.8 28 46 12.2-6.9 5-22.4 4.6-38 .9-11.2 6-22.5 3-38-4.3-24-13-39-19.3-35.2z',
  'M5161.6 3339.1c5.4 5.4 39.3 7.3 60.5-10.3 20-16.6 21.1-41 15.7-44.8-6.7-4.8-40.7 2.6-47.9 6.2-19.7 10.1-36.5 40.8-28.3 49z',
  'M5232.8 2740.6c-7.8 9.9-16.5 20-26 27-9.5 6.8-19.3 10-29 15 3 8 2.5 14.5 5 19 5.5 9.9 42.2-1.4 53-5 10.8-3.7 39.9-7.5 46 7 6.3 14.4-9 18-18 21.4-21.5 8-39.8 9.5-36 29.6 5.2 27.5 41.6 22.8 83 6 27.7-16 35.8-25 35.6-52-.3-28.2-36.9-54.5-51.9-61.7-25.5-12.3-60.5-6.6-61.7-6.3z',
  'M3686.6 3950.5a102 102 0 0 0-46.7 52c-17.5 49.8 25.5 64 37.9 60.2 6.4-2 15.5-12.5 28.9-12.3 16.4-.6 23 10.9 45.1 12.2 11.8.6 14.6-21 19.2-26.7 9.3-11.5 21.2-17.3 21.8-33.3s-3.6-21.2-20.4-35.5c-13.8-12.2-69-25.2-85.8-16.6z',
  'M5052.9 210c-26.3 123 76 147 135.8 142.4 28.6-2.1 138.5-50.5 125.6-151.3-11.9-93.2-103.6-110.5-143.3-104.3s-90.6 41.5-118.1 113.2z',
  'M5753.7 664c-2.3 2.3-2.8 27.5-.6 29.6 2.2 2 55.1 6.3 59 3.4 4-2.8 17.6-29.4 14.4-31.8-3.1-2.3-70.5-3.6-72.8-1.3z',
  'M4795.3 1204.8c-8.7 5.8 6 24 20.5 34.4s50.3 8.7 59.8 6.1 24-10.7 23.3-17c-.4-4.2-15-14.9-45.6-22.4-27.4-6.8-49.8-6.5-58-1z',
  'M4106.1 3587.2c-10 5.5-7.7 11-23.5 20.9-7.6 4.7-23.2 23-21.7 57.5 1.6 34.4 26 54.4 43.9 52 18-2.5 23.5-4.6 53-23 25.7-13.5 39.8-28.3 43.5-62.8 1.8-18-26.4-44-44.1-46.5-24-3.3-41-3.6-51 2z',
  'm4663.8 1927.6 121.4-85.2c21.3-2.5 26.5-5.4 41.6-18.7a65 65 0 0 0 24.3-38.3c-14.6-33.1-33.1-60.5-51.3-91.8 48.6-4.5 89.8 9.4 136 23 47.2 13.8 68.7 28.8 91.9 41.1-15.6 18.5-14.4 23.9-21 46-6.9 33.6-4 34.3 19.1 58.9 14.7 29.5 35.6 37.2 59.5 41.4l109.5 112.6c-8.5 12.2-8 25.9-5 40 34.7 57.8-3.3-4.2 57 104-7 8-14.4 16.3-24 21-12.1 5.9-27.3 10.3-39 4l-13-7c-82.3-60.4-162.8-124-258-163-10.6-25-25.2-41.6-35-44-9.3-2.4-38.7 7.8-56.9 19.2-52.3-22.3-126.8-20.8-157.1-63.2z',
];

class ClimbingWall extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClimbingWall({
    super.key,
    required this.image,
    required this.imageSize,
    required this.holds,
  });

  final ImageProvider image;
  final Size imageSize;
  final List<(String, Color)> holds;

  @override
  State<ClimbingWall> createState() => _ClimbingWallState();
}

class _ClimbingWallState extends State<ClimbingWall> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late List<Path> paths;
  late Size size;
  final transformationController = TransformationController();
  late final moveController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Durations.extralong4);
  Animatable<Matrix4> moveTween = Matrix4Tween();
  int idx = 7;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    moveController.addListener(() {
      transformationController.value = moveTween.transform(moveController.value);
    });

    paths = widget.holds.map((hold) => parseSvgPathData(hold.$1)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        size = constraints.biggest;

        _moveTo(idx);
        // final matrix = sizeToRect(originalImageSize, Offset.zero & size,
        //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
        //   alignment: const Alignment(0.6, 0),
        // );
        // controller.value = matrix;

        print('LayoutBuilder view: $size, fixed image size: ${widget.imageSize}');
        return Stack(
          children: [
            InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: transformationController,
              minScale: 0.1,
              maxScale: 5,
              constrained: false,
              child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                size: widget.imageSize,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Image(
                      image: widget.image,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                        return loadingProgress == null? child : Container(color: Colors.grey.shade800);
                      },
                    ),
                    ...paths.mapIndexed((i, path) => Positioned.fromRect(
                      rect: path.getBounds(),
                      child: Container(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                          shape: HoldShape(path, transformationController),
                          gradient: RadialGradient(
                            colors: [Colors.white, widget.holds[i].$2],
                            center: const Alignment(-0.5, -0.5),
                          ),
                          shadows: const [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 6, offset: Offset(6, 6))],
                        ),
                        child: Material(
                          type: MaterialType.transparency,
                          child: InkWell(
                            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                            splashColor: Colors.orange,
                            child: FittedBox(child: Text('#$i')),
                            onTap: () {
                              print('hold $i clicked');
                              _moveTo(idx = i);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: IconButton.filledTonal(
                  onPressed: () {
                    idx = (idx - 1) % paths.length;
                    _moveTo(idx);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: IconButton.filledTonal(
                  onPressed: () {
                    idx = (idx + 1) % paths.length;
                    _moveTo(idx);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _moveTo(int i) {
    final matrix = rectToRect(paths[i].getBounds(), Offset.zero & size,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
    );
    moveTween = Matrix4Tween(begin: transformationController.value, end: matrix)
      .chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut));
    moveController.forward(from: 0);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    transformationController.dispose();
    moveController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class HoldShape extends ShapeBorder {
  HoldShape(Path path, this.controller) : path = shiftPath(path);

  final ui.Path path;
  final TransformationController controller;

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.zero;

  @override
  ui.Path getInnerPath(ui.Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) => getOuterPath(rect);

  @override
  ui.Path getOuterPath(ui.Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) => path.shift(rect.topLeft);

  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    final strokeWidth = 8 / controller.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
    final p = path.shift(rect.topLeft);
    canvas
      ..save()
      ..clipPath(p)
      ..drawPath(p, Paint()
        ..color = Colors.white70
        ..style = ui.PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      )
      ..restore();
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;

  static Path shiftPath(ui.Path path) {
    final offset = path.getBounds().topLeft;
    return path.shift(-offset);
  }
}

Matrix4 sizeToRect(Size src, Rect dst, {BoxFit fit = BoxFit.contain, Alignment alignment = Alignment.center}) {
  FittedSizes fs = applyBoxFit(fit, src, dst.size);
  double scaleX = fs.destination.width / fs.source.width;
  double scaleY = fs.destination.height / fs.source.height;
  Size fittedSrc = Size(src.width * scaleX, src.height * scaleY);
  Rect out = alignment.inscribe(fittedSrc, dst);

  return Matrix4.identity()
    ..translate(out.left, out.top)
    ..scale(scaleX, scaleY);
}

Matrix4 rectToRect(Rect src, Rect dst, {BoxFit fit = BoxFit.contain, Alignment alignment = Alignment.center}) {
  return sizeToRect(src.size, dst, fit: fit, alignment: alignment)
    ..translate(-src.left, -src.top);
}

EDIT
this is a solution with a single CustomPaint widget that in theory should work even with 1000s of holds as it uses spatial search:
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
import 'package:path_drawing/path_drawing.dart';
import 'package:rbush/rbush.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
      body: ClimbingWall(
        image: NetworkImage('http://localhost/flutter/32da338c-f6b2-4abf-88a9-647923166afe.webp'),
        imageSize: Size(6400, 4247),
        holdsPathData: holdsPathData,
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

const holdsPathData = [
  'M5077.8 981.7c2.3 50.2 59.9 36.4 94.7 35.9 26.5-2.7 80-13.7 74.3-68-10.7-24.6-34.4-22.2-46.9-19.1s-14.9 10.2-46 15.6c-31 5.3-67.4-11.8-76.1 35.6z',
  'm4011 1797.7 51.8-48.1-13-97c30.2 7.7 24.2 9 55 9 27 0 84.1-1.3 118.8-8 13.5 21.3 18.9 38.8 30.7 62l-9.5 85-18 30c-23 2.7-37.9 1.2-69 2-31.1.7-106.9-6.9-146.8-35z',
  'M4377.1 3248.4c-6.6 4-3.4 26-5.5 35.8s-10.3 14.6-10.8 29.4c-.9 26.1 6.9 57.8 28 46 12.2-6.9 5-22.4 4.6-38 .9-11.2 6-22.5 3-38-4.3-24-13-39-19.3-35.2z',
  'M5161.6 3339.1c5.4 5.4 39.3 7.3 60.5-10.3 20-16.6 21.1-41 15.7-44.8-6.7-4.8-40.7 2.6-47.9 6.2-19.7 10.1-36.5 40.8-28.3 49z',
  'M5232.8 2740.6c-7.8 9.9-16.5 20-26 27-9.5 6.8-19.3 10-29 15 3 8 2.5 14.5 5 19 5.5 9.9 42.2-1.4 53-5 10.8-3.7 39.9-7.5 46 7 6.3 14.4-9 18-18 21.4-21.5 8-39.8 9.5-36 29.6 5.2 27.5 41.6 22.8 83 6 27.7-16 35.8-25 35.6-52-.3-28.2-36.9-54.5-51.9-61.7-25.5-12.3-60.5-6.6-61.7-6.3z',
  'M3686.6 3950.5a102 102 0 0 0-46.7 52c-17.5 49.8 25.5 64 37.9 60.2 6.4-2 15.5-12.5 28.9-12.3 16.4-.6 23 10.9 45.1 12.2 11.8.6 14.6-21 19.2-26.7 9.3-11.5 21.2-17.3 21.8-33.3s-3.6-21.2-20.4-35.5c-13.8-12.2-69-25.2-85.8-16.6z',
  'M5052.9 210c-26.3 123 76 147 135.8 142.4 28.6-2.1 138.5-50.5 125.6-151.3-11.9-93.2-103.6-110.5-143.3-104.3s-90.6 41.5-118.1 113.2z',
  'M5753.7 664c-2.3 2.3-2.8 27.5-.6 29.6 2.2 2 55.1 6.3 59 3.4 4-2.8 17.6-29.4 14.4-31.8-3.1-2.3-70.5-3.6-72.8-1.3z',
  'M4795.3 1204.8c-8.7 5.8 6 24 20.5 34.4s50.3 8.7 59.8 6.1 24-10.7 23.3-17c-.4-4.2-15-14.9-45.6-22.4-27.4-6.8-49.8-6.5-58-1z',
  'M4106.1 3587.2c-10 5.5-7.7 11-23.5 20.9-7.6 4.7-23.2 23-21.7 57.5 1.6 34.4 26 54.4 43.9 52 18-2.5 23.5-4.6 53-23 25.7-13.5 39.8-28.3 43.5-62.8 1.8-18-26.4-44-44.1-46.5-24-3.3-41-3.6-51 2z',
  'm4663.8 1927.6 121.4-85.2c21.3-2.5 26.5-5.4 41.6-18.7a65 65 0 0 0 24.3-38.3c-14.6-33.1-33.1-60.5-51.3-91.8 48.6-4.5 89.8 9.4 136 23 47.2 13.8 68.7 28.8 91.9 41.1-15.6 18.5-14.4 23.9-21 46-6.9 33.6-4 34.3 19.1 58.9 14.7 29.5 35.6 37.2 59.5 41.4l109.5 112.6c-8.5 12.2-8 25.9-5 40 34.7 57.8-3.3-4.2 57 104-7 8-14.4 16.3-24 21-12.1 5.9-27.3 10.3-39 4l-13-7c-82.3-60.4-162.8-124-258-163-10.6-25-25.2-41.6-35-44-9.3-2.4-38.7 7.8-56.9 19.2-52.3-22.3-126.8-20.8-157.1-63.2z',
];

class ClimbingWall extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClimbingWall({
    super.key,
    required this.image,
    required this.imageSize,
    required this.holdsPathData,
  });

  final ImageProvider image;
  final Size imageSize;
  final List<String> holdsPathData;

  @override
  State<ClimbingWall> createState() => _ClimbingWallState();
}

class _ClimbingWallState extends State<ClimbingWall> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final selectionController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Durations.medium4);
  late final opacityController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Durations.medium4);
  late List<Path> allPaths;
  Size size = Size.zero;
  final transformationController = TransformationController();
  final selectedPath = ValueNotifier<Path?>(null);
  final visiblePaths = ValueNotifier<List<Path>>([]);
  final holdsTree = RBush<Path>(16);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    transformationController.addListener(() {
      // find all visible paths
      final topLeft = transformationController.toScene(Offset.zero);
      final bottomRight = transformationController.toScene(size.bottomRight(Offset.zero));
      final viewportBox = RBushBox(
        minX: topLeft.dx,
        minY: topLeft.dy,
        maxX: bottomRight.dx,
        maxY: bottomRight.dy,
      );
      visiblePaths.value = holdsTree.search(viewportBox).map((e) => e.data).toList();

      // draw paths in ClimbingWallPainter if scale > some factor (here 0.4) or
      // number of visible paths < some max number (here 5)
      transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis() > 0.4 ||
      (visiblePaths.value.length < 5 && visiblePaths.value.isNotEmpty)?
        opacityController.forward() :
        opacityController.reverse();
    });

    allPaths = widget.holdsPathData.map((pathData) => parseSvgPathData(pathData)).toList();
    visiblePaths.value = allPaths;

    final allElements = allPaths.map((p) {
      final bounds = p.getBounds();
      return RBushElement(
        minX: bounds.left,
        minY: bounds.top,
        maxX: bounds.right,
        maxY: bounds.bottom,
        data: p,
      );
    });
    holdsTree.load(allElements);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        size = constraints.biggest;

        final matrix = sizeToRect(widget.imageSize, Offset.zero & size,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          alignment: const Alignment(0.6, 0),
        );
        transformationController.value = matrix;

        print('LayoutBuilder view: $size, fixed image size: ${widget.imageSize}');
        return Stack(
          children: [
            InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: transformationController,
              minScale: 0.1,
              maxScale: 5,
              constrained: false,
              child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                size: widget.imageSize,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTapDown: (d) {
                    print('finding tap down in ${visiblePaths.value.length} paths');
                    selectedPath.value = visiblePaths.value.firstWhereOrNull((path) {
                      return path.contains(d.localPosition);
                    });
                    print(selectedPath.value != null? "found a path" : "nothing found");
                    if (selectedPath.value != null) {
                      selectionController.forward();
                    }
                  },
                  onTapUp: (d) => selectionController.reverse(),
                  onTapCancel: () => selectionController.reverse(),
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    foregroundPainter: ClimbingWallPainter(
                      visiblePaths: visiblePaths,
                      selectedPath: selectedPath,
                      transformationController: transformationController,
                      selectionController: selectionController,
                      opacityController: opacityController,
                    ),
                    child: Image(
                      image: widget.image,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                        return loadingProgress == null? child : Container(color: Colors.grey.shade800);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: visiblePaths,
                builder: (ctx, value, child) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: Text('number of possible visible paths: ${value.length}'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    transformationController.dispose();
    selectionController.dispose();
    opacityController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

Matrix4 sizeToRect(Size src, Rect dst, {BoxFit fit = BoxFit.contain, Alignment alignment = Alignment.center}) {
  FittedSizes fs = applyBoxFit(fit, src, dst.size);
  double scaleX = fs.destination.width / fs.source.width;
  double scaleY = fs.destination.height / fs.source.height;
  Size fittedSrc = Size(src.width * scaleX, src.height * scaleY);
  Rect out = alignment.inscribe(fittedSrc, dst);

  return Matrix4.identity()
    ..translate(out.left, out.top)
    ..scale(scaleX, scaleY);
}

Matrix4 rectToRect(Rect src, Rect dst, {BoxFit fit = BoxFit.contain, Alignment alignment = Alignment.center}) {
  return sizeToRect(src.size, dst, fit: fit, alignment: alignment)
    ..translate(-src.left, -src.top);
}

class ClimbingWallPainter extends CustomPainter {
  ClimbingWallPainter({
    required this.visiblePaths,
    required this.selectedPath,
    required this.transformationController,
    required this.selectionController,
    required this.opacityController,
  }) : super(repaint: Listenable.merge([selectionController, opacityController]));

  final ValueNotifier<List<Path>> visiblePaths;
  final ValueNotifier<Path?> selectedPath;
  final TransformationController transformationController;
  final AnimationController selectionController;
  final AnimationController opacityController;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // timeDilation = 10;
    if (opacityController.value > 0) {
      print('painting ${visiblePaths.value.length} paths with opacity ${opacityController.value}');
      final opacity = opacityController.value;

      final normalFillPaint = Paint()
        ..color = Colors.white24;
      final normalBorderPaint = Paint()
        ..style = ui.PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = 8
        ..color = Colors.orange;
      final selectedFillPaint = Paint()
        ..color = Color.lerp(normalFillPaint.color, Colors.white54, selectionController.value)!;
      final selectedBorderPaint = Paint()
        ..style = ui.PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = ui.lerpDouble(8, 16, selectionController.value)!
        ..color = Color.lerp(normalBorderPaint.color, Colors.deepOrange, selectionController.value)!;

      normalFillPaint.color = normalFillPaint.color.applyOpacity(opacity);
      selectedFillPaint.color = selectedFillPaint.color.applyOpacity(opacity);
      normalBorderPaint.color = normalBorderPaint.color.applyOpacity(opacity);
      selectedBorderPaint.color = selectedBorderPaint.color.applyOpacity(opacity);

      for (final path in visiblePaths.value) {
        canvas
          ..drawPath(path, path == selectedPath.value? selectedFillPaint : normalFillPaint)
          ..drawPath(path, path == selectedPath.value? selectedBorderPaint : normalBorderPaint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(ClimbingWallPainter oldDelegate) => false;

}

extension on Color {
  Color applyOpacity(double opacity) => withOpacity(this.opacity * opacity);
}


That looks awesome, thanks for the effort! I converged to a similar solution but using CustomPaint painter and foregroundPainter. https://gist.github.com/raspbeep/5df9bfb6eb6af2b1fb08622e35d1d281
One possible drawback of your solution is, that at some point, I need to have over 1500 polygons (holds) listening for events at once and that there would be a performance penalty having all the holds as widgets. On the other hand, in my solution the gesture detection is finicky right now. Which solution would be more suitable in your opinion taking into account the performance considerations?

Also, the zoom behavior into a particular "hold" is not really desirable. I want to have only the outline and the dstOut effect (extrusion into a dimming layer as is in my example). Is there any way to add the extrude-into-a-dimming-layer effect to your solution?

You are a beast. I put both of them to test https://gist.github.com/raspbeep/b868aa76625b976aac7ba48849c687c7 with the full polygon count (1205). Findings are: both can produce laggy result. The CustomPaint averages 86fps, with fps increasing when zooming in. The Positioned.rect runs around 60fps but is janky all the way since it always draws all the polygons no matter the zoom. Seems like the optimal implementation would combine the R-trees and Positioned.rect (yet, I would love to have the extrusion effect, which afaik is only plausible with CustomPaint.)

In the end, I decided to go with CustomPaint and R-tree implementation. The real use case is that the polygons are all transparent, listening for events and the user than selects (taps) only a small subset (<30). I found that the transparent color for the majority of the polygons helps the performance a lot (basically full refresh rate even on older devices). Thanks a lot, your examples were priceless!
